# jQuery Ajax DOM Exception 12

Tags: jquery, ajax, exception, dom

I'm trying to send a get request using

```
$.get('/').done(function() {
    alert('assdsdasasd');
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
});
```

but the fail handler is invoked and it alerts me *"Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12"*

Where does this error come from and how can I fix this?

Comment: This error is normally seen when the data received is not in the format expected. For example, mal-formed HTML or JSON.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Unfortunately the resource with the request being sent doesn't appear in Safari's Development Console. How can I debug this?

Btw: dataType is normally set to Intelligent Guess, isn't it?

Comment: It is, although it's based on the first few characters of the returned data IIRC. So if it thinks the response is JSON, but there are formatting errors you'll see this error. Try using Chrome DevTools